# Elementary derivation of the Taylor series of $\sin x$ that might have been devised by Madhava of Sangamagrama

Tags: taylor-expansion

I can derive the Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$ by the Taylor's theorem.

But what is an elementary approach to derive this series?
I mean the way [Madhava of Sangamagrama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama) (c.1340–c.1425) or his contemporaries had possibly derived.

Comment: I searched google and found this 

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5cb2/4ef31a09a66625a26a74de59273dff5bb232.pdf

Comment: I highly recommend The Mathematics of the Heavens and the Earth The Early History of Trigonometry https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8956.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, Madhava of Sangamagrama had enough of calculus available to know what we would write as $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin x=\cos x$ and $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos x=\sin x$, hence $\frac {\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\sin x=-\sin x$ as well as $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$. Then comparing coefficients of a series ansatz
$$\sin x=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\ldots $$
with its second derivative together with the elementary observation that $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$ (i.e., $\sin x\approx x$ for small $x$) directly leads to 
$$\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\mp\ldots $$
though the question of convergence may not have been dealt with rigorously (beyond justification by numerical evidence perhaps).

Comment: Comparing coefficients requires the knowledge of Taylor's theorem which he was perhaps unaware of. One may obtain the series of $e^x$ (by Binomial theorem) or, arctan (x) without any sort to Taylor's theorem. I was looking for similar approach.